# Input for LSI, LDA and HDP?

Tags: topic-models, latent-dirichlet-alloc, tf-idf, latent-semantic-analysis

It seems that the Latent Semantic Indexing (LSI or Latent Semantic Analysis, LSA) can take as input information frequency data (such as  TfIdf-weighted space), e.g., according to this documentation for gensim https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/core/run_topics_and_transformations.html#available-transformations.

Can the "probabilistic extension of LSI", the Latent Dirichlet Allocation (LDA) or the Hierarchical Dirichlet Process (HDP) model take only counts (bag-of-word) data? According to the underlying statistical model, this appears to me to be case. However, the models in gensim can also take real-valued data as input.

**Is using the real-valued data, such as relative term frequencies, as input data correct in terms of underlying statistical model for LDA and HDP?**

**Which input data is correct in terms of underlying statistical model for LSI?** Does it conceptually work with any real value input data? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_analysis#Latent_semantic_indexing)

Comment: Great question! Yes, according to the generative distribution, it's not possible to use fractional weights, such as TFiDF weights, for LDA. However, there are tons of heuristics that do just this; "weighted" latent dirichlet allocation is a good search term. Some of them even claim to come with generative models, such as this one: https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.5555/1857999.1858069

Comment: Thank you John. I'll go through your referenced paper in detail and look for the mentioned alternatives. I think this answers the questions. For LSI/LSA the underlying statistical model seems to be closely related to a truncated SVD. The sklearn documentation on truncated SVD (scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/…) states the following: "In particular, truncated SVD works on term count/tf-idf matrices as returned by the vectorizers in sklearn.feature_extraction.text. In that context, it is known as latent semantic analysis (LSA)."

Comment: Another great question (I say this self-flatteringly, because I once was confused by both of these things)! Yes, LSA is literally just SVD/PCA.